# What is the etymology of 'bucket' in cloud computing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, storage, bucket

Correct me if I am wrong, but I haven't found any explanation out there and in stackoverflow. All I've found was "what it does" not "why it's named like that" .

I get the idea about bucket. Mainly it's for storage of objects in cloud computing.

Is someone can explain a little history of buckets and who's the one responsible of naming "bucket"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage Did you take a look at this site?

Comment: @AshBlake yes I have. Unfortunately didn't answer the question on "bucket"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from hash functions used in C programming. Hashing is a method of looking up data. The hash results in slots also called buckets. Storage was named buckets because of the math used to locate objects. To understand hashing, Google search for **hash tables**.

As far as I know (I was there), Amazon chose the name buckets for cloud object storage and the rest of the industry followed.

Comment: You are "mathematic", I'm more "poetic"!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the history, but you have to view it as a real bucket, and in opposition of a tree.

Usual file system are represented as a tree, because there are banches (folders) and leaves (the files).

Object storage doesn't have that architecture, it's a bucket, a pot. You put all the things (the object) in it. No hierarchy, no sorting, no organisation, all at the root level, in bulk.